# Opening a file for editing

Tags: file, file-io, jframe, frame

I want to create a method that will load a txt file and then change it but thats another method.

```
private void openFile() {
    fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    JFileChooser openFile = new JFileChooser();
    openFile.showOpenDialog(frame);
}
```

What must go next in order to get data from the file after choosing it to manipulate its data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JFileChooser documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) has an example on how to continue your code, and get the name of the file chosen, which can then be turned into a [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object. You should be able to modify that example to meet your needs:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
    "JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
        chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that might help you. I would want to read up on and try some simple examples on different buffers that will read and write. In fact, i have worked with these a lot in the last few months and I still have to go and look.

```
public class ReadWriteTextFile {
      static public String getContents(File aFile) {
      StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();

    try {
         BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
      try {
        String line = null; //not declared within while loop
        while (( line = input.readLine()) != null){
          contents.append(line);
          contents.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
      }
      finally {
        input.close();
      }
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return contents.toString();
  }

    static public void setContents(File aFile, 
                                   String aContents)
                                      throws FileNotFoundException, 
                                             IOException {
    if (aFile == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("File should not be null.");
    }
    if (!aFile.exists()) {
      throw new FileNotFoundException ("File does not exist: " + aFile);
    }
    if (!aFile.isFile()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Should not be a directory: " + aFile);
    }
    if (!aFile.canWrite()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("File cannot be written: " + aFile);
    }

      Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(aFile));
    try {
      output.write( aContents );
    }
    finally {
      output.close();
    }
  }

  public static void main (String... aArguments) throws IOException {
    File testFile = new File("C:\\Temp\\test.txt");//this file might have to exist (I am not 
                                                   //certain but you can trap the error with a
                                                   //TRY-CATCH Block.
    System.out.println("Original file contents: " + getContents(testFile));
    setContents(testFile, "The content of this file has been overwritten...");
    System.out.println("New file contents: " + getContents(testFile));
  }
}
```